# Calculating distance dynamically in SQL query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, geospatial

I've been grokking the 'net for answers as to how to dynamically calculate and return the distance to a set of provided GPS coordinates for each row in a MySQL/Mariadb table (using Geospatial extensions).

My query is as follows: (I'm using an arbitrary GPS Coordinate as placeholder instead of dynamically generating the query for a supplied coordinate).

```
SET @distance = 0;
select name, X(location), Y(location), 
@distance = (((ACOS(SIN( 17.4681194 * PI() / 180) 
* SIN(X(location) * PI() / 180) + COS(17.4681194 * PI() / 180) 
* COS(X(location) * PI() / 180) * COS((78.495423 - Y(location)) 
* PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
* 1.609) 
as distance from Points
```

The problem is that in my output, all distances are either 0 or 1. I'd carefully seeded the Points table, so I know these values are wrong.

The reason i'm doing this in the SQL and not in Python (or at the code level) is because I want to be able to use ORDER BY and TOP once I get the distances done right and take the 3 closest locations from the table.

My output is as follows:

```
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| name           | X(location)        | Y(location)       | distance |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| randomsr1      |         17.4901059 |        78.4819368 |        0 |
| randomsr2      |         17.4895687 |        78.4830526 |        0 |
| randomsr3      |           17.45602 |         78.448551 |        0 |
| randomsr4      |         17.4681194 |         78.495423 |        1 |
| randomsra      |          17.515589 |        78.4749738 |        0 |
| randomsrb      |         17.4041657 |        78.4930975 |        0 |
| randomsrc      |  17.40658541008292 | 78.47815974049286 |        0 |
| randomsrd      | 17.468381171457448 | 78.46161846857831 |        0 |
| randomsr6      |   17.4649552904376 | 78.45982138853833 |        0 |
| location5      |          17.515562 |         78.474973 |        0 |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Nice output. Thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome, but if you're referring to the beautification, that's all MySQL/MariaDB. :)

Comment: I know the question was really a simple one, but can anyone tell me why I got downvoted? I am not an expert at MySQL by any measure, and this was a learning experience for me. 

Perhaps the message to me is 'sleep over your problems before coming over to SO' ?

Comment: For next time see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, dumb question. I'd missed out an '**:**' before the '**=**' when assigning the values computed to the variable.

```
select name, X(location), Y(location), 
@distance := (((ACOS(SIN( 17.4681194 * PI() / 180) 
* SIN(X(location) * PI() / 180) + COS(17.4681194 * PI() / 180) 
* COS(X(location) * PI() / 180) * COS((78.495423 - Y(location)) 
* PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
* 1.609) 
as distance from Points;
```

now returns :

```
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| name           | X(location)        | Y(location)       | distance           |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| randomsr1      |         17.4901059 |        78.4819368 |  2.831730948299528 |
| randomsr2      |         17.4895687 |        78.4830526 | 2.7213934426686652 |
| randomsr3      |           17.45602 |         78.448551 |  5.149213292389459 |
| randomsr4      |         17.4681194 |         78.495423 |                  0 |
| randomsra      |          17.515589 |        78.4749738 |  5.705042143392742 |
| randomsrb      |         17.4041657 |        78.4930975 | 7.1137416855834115 |
| randomsrc      |  17.40658541008292 | 78.47815974049286 |  7.081262494869047 |
| randomsrd      | 17.468381171457448 | 78.46161846857831 | 3.5847244189457905 |
| randomsr6      |   17.4649552904376 | 78.45982138853833 | 3.7915534696376625 |
| location5      |          17.515562 |         78.474973 |  5.702298292174848 |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```